How to reorder pages after rendering?
I have a document with, say, 10 pages. I need to show it to someone, but with a different order of pages, placing page 4 and page 5 at the top of the document, while all other pages should go in their normal order. I don't want to modify the content. Instead, something like this is desirable:
\documentclass{article}
\ThisPagesGoFirst{4,5}  % here!
\begin{document}
% the content without changes
\end{document}

Maybe a package exists that can do this?

How about just using the PDF Toolkit to reorder the content after the document is created?

or use a second document which just reorders the pages with e.g. pdfpages?

@Werner GUI icing for 3.99?

@cfr: Well, there's also a portable version that works for $0.

@Werner they are being deliberately misleading, imho. 'pdftk server' appears to be pdftk wich is a cli tool which has been around for years. it may be used on servers, but so may almost anything. they say you need a 'commercial license' to distribute it 'with' a commercial programme. as far as I know, there is nothing to stop microsoft distributing GPL software with windows. GPL may be 'viral' but it isn't that infectious.

@Werner for the record, I wouldn't object if they were upfront about it. I think they do actually maintain the GPL tool. but they're exploiting people's ignorance, especially Windows users.

You can also look for PanteraPDF for Windows, which provides a GUI for what pdfpages would do for you with Latex.

You cannot reorder pages in an ordinary, straightforward compilation because TeX ships pages out as they are typeset.
You could reorder it on a second compilation, I suppose, but bursting the PDF and just including pages from it.
Or you could, if you had sufficient memory or a sufficiently short document, probably save the pages into memory rather than outputting them right away.
But any of these schemes would introduce considerable complexity and to no purpose. Far easier to simply have two documents.
We can use a second document which merely includes the pages we want in the order we want from our file, mypdf.pdf, say.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages={4-5}]{mypdf}
\includepdf[pages={1,3,2}]{mypdf}
\end{document}


Users should remember that this removes any meta layers, for example hyperlinks.

@daleif isn't it a bit worse, actually? I thought it broke them rather than removing them? I did think about that, but if you really want to reorder pages without changing the document, is there a practical alternative? all the options I can think of would at least require additional markup inside the document body.

not sure. Doesn't the leaflet class do some strange stuff? Though do not remember if it recorders. The pgfpages feature still prints the pages in order even if it typeset 8 pages on one.
